# How to say "I look" as in "I look stupid" in French?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, expressions

How do you say "I look" as in "I look pretty/stupid/etc"? Do you use ressemble?

Also, out of topic: how do you say "you seem adjective", and how do you express "pretty" as in "That's pretty dumb"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"To look" + adjective in French can be said a couple different ways.

> "Avoir l'air______", e.g. "J'ai l'air ridicule."
>
> "Paraître______" e.g. "Elle paraît fatiguée."
>
> "Sembler______" e.g. "Ça semble intéressant !"

"pretty" can be said a few different ways as well, depending on the context.

> "Plutôt"
>
> "Assez"

are the most commonly used.

For your examples, you could say:

> "J'ai l'air plutôt ridicule."
>
> "Elle paraît assez fatiguée."
>
> "Ça semble plutôt/assez intéressant !"

Answer (score 1):

"J'ai l'air ... " is the most versatile one.
You can use it in 
J'ai l'air bête (I look stupid)
Tu as l'air fatigué (You look tired)

While you would not say "je semble bête" or "je parais bête"
(you wouldn't say "I seem stupid" in English either)